# How can I line up my text with CSS so it appears at the top of a table?

Tags: css

I am a bit confused. Should I use top or text-top? I found reference to both but I'm not sure which to use. All I have is a simple table with two rows and two columns. I would like the text to be aligned to the top and to the left in each cell. What's the most easy way for me to do this? Can I do it without lots of CSS and use inheritance?

Comment: Your question is really about the difference between `vertical-align:top` and `vertical-align:text-top`, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your css file configure the td style and add vertical-align: top;
This will align all the data in between  and  on the top of the table and aligned left

Answer (score 1):

try

```
table td { vertical-align:top; float:left }
```

**Reference:**

### [vertical-align](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align)

### [float](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/float)

Comment: Using `float:left` is actually misleading, since it applies the style to the table cell, not the cell's contents. If you want to be really picky, you don't need to say `table td` either, since all `td` elements will be inside a table.

Comment: @derekerdmann; see the OP , he write " I would like the text to be aligned to the top and to the left in **each cell**."  and table cell will not floated left. only contents will floated left as i apply the rule for `td`

Comment: But `table td { float:left }` is trying to float the `<td>`, not its content.

Comment: @mu then we can use `text-align:left` instead. is that working??

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, text is aligned left by default in tables.  Is that a browser-by-browser issue?

Answer (score 1):

@TonyG; Check    **[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/dAMJd/)** may be that's you want.

there are different selectors for this type of functionality like `:first-child` , `:last-child` & `nth-child()`.

```
td:nth-child(1){
    vertical-align: top;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you should need to do is add `vertical-align: top;` to your `td` styles.

Here's a *very* simple example: http://jsbin.com/usego3/2